# Which Windows raw image viewer can only show jpeg, but on delete both raw and jpeg?

Tags: raw, jpeg, windows, photo-management, photo-viewer

I'm searching for an image viewer with the following features:
(situation is, that both jpeg and raw are saved)

- windows (7) support
- when clicking through pictures only show jpeg
- when deleting photo, delete both raw and jpeg
- auto-rotate at EXIF-rotate attribute
- freeware

At the moment I use Faststone Image viewer, which has all wished features except show only jpeg (if raw exists) and delete both raw and jpeg.

Comment: I think that those "only show jpeg" and "delete both" requirements are going to be difficult to fulfill. I've not heard of anything that does that.

Comment: If you have a Linux VM, use Geeqie. It does exactly that by default and is quite fast too.

Comment: At the risk of going off on a rant, why must it be free? After all, like photographers, software engineers need to be able to pay bills too. Until we get to a Star Trek utopia of a society without currency, it seems like an unusual requirement for a creative professional to have (and without that requirement Lightroom would fit, and do a whole load more)

Comment: @Itai: THANKS for this tip - it seams to be fine and I'll give it a closer look to it. :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: I agree with you and know what it means to develop a software and how many work is behind it! But for applications, which I need for one of my hobbies (w/o high prof.) I try to use free software, if possible. For business, no doubt about buying SW. In additional I also know someone who developed freeware and after then got some assignments for commercial development - an example how freeware-dev can help for career. ;)

Comment: Well, if you have a Linux system (physical or VM) you should also consider Darktable.   It's (apparently) like Lightroom.

Comment: Chris, could you please explain why RAW + JPEG scheme is better that just having RAW files with built-in JPEG previews? In the second case - almost any decent photo management software or image viewer can render RAW files using built-in JPEG previews. You will avoided possible RAW + JPEG syncing problems and issues with deleting both files simultaneously.

Comment: Double format mode is intended for scenarios such as "I want an immediate sharing ability/I'm often fine with the default in-camera rendering/… but I want a chance to fix it in PP if I have/want to", the embedded preview is (at least with certain cameras such as the D3100) of absymal quality for viewing.

Comment: XnView can be configure to do exactly what you want. It is free and known as the swiss-army-knife-of-image-viewers. However, IMHO it has an uncomfortable and ugly GUI, and you have to press a lot of CTRL/ALT keys. Something like Lightroom is actually cheaper than wasting time with these antique (but free) image viewers rooting in the 90s.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with XnView.
In the meantime I also invest in Adobe LR. ;)
But nevertheless a good workflow is to do a first sort of all pictures with the FastPictureViewer (which is really fast) and afterthen Adobe LR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tool: [FastPictureViewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/)

I'm not sure if there is a free version available but for those who are intrested in buying a viewer that's able to do this... Just take a look :)

Comment: Thank you, looks also good! Here the license info from [www.fastpictureviewer.com](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/faq/#license): 
"FastPictureViewer Home Basic Edition (which supports JPEG and Microsoft HD Photo) is available free of charge for personal, non-profit or educational uses (freeware license)."

Comment: Wow, this pic viewer is REALY veeery fast and is exactly (!) what I searched for. I'll test it for a while and think about buying it... In spite of my comment above, I didn't found the free version download. Maybe it doesn't exist anymore.
@ThomasDekiere: Many thanks!! :)